# Redirect one vhost to another vhost with SSL in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, redirect

Here is my situation: I have two CNAME domains (`domain.one.com` and `domain.two.com`) that point to the same IP/machine and I want to redirect one of the two to the other one, like `domain.one.com/anything` to `domain.two.com/anything`. `domain.two.com` has a valid SSL certificate, if it matters.

And I have the following settings:

In `httpd.conf`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^domain\.two\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://domain.two.com/$1 [L,R]

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost domain.two.com:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.two.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit
</VirtualHost>
```

In `ssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost domain.two.com:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName domain.two.com:443
</VirtualHost>
```

--

What I have tried so far:

Adding to `httpd.conf` the following:

```
NameVirtualHost domain.one.com:443

<VirtualHost domain.one.com:80>
    ServerName domain.one.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.one.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.two.com/$1 [R=Permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

- **Doesn’t redirect.**

Also adding the following to `ssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost domain.one.com:443>
    ServerName domain.one.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.one.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.two.com/$1 [R=Permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

- **The server stops working.**

I know I’m doing something wrong, but I don’t know what. How can I make this work?

(I should mention that I’m a noob in these things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use A record over CNAME in DNS settings to simplify the proceedings. Refer [Differences between the A, CNAME, ALIAS and URL records](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/)

Following vhost config would fulfill your requirement.

1) **HTTP** domain.one.com to **HTTPS** domain.two.com

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain.one.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$       "https://domain.two.com$1" [R,L]

    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName domain.two.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/your.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/your.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/chain.crt

    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

2) For both **HTTP** and **HTTPS** domain.one.com to **HTTPS** domain.two.com

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain.one.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$       "https://domain.two.com$1" [R,L]

    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName domain.one.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$       "https://domain.two.com$1" [R,L]

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/your.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/your.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/chain.crt

    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName domain.two.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/your.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/your.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/chain.crt

    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where should I put these settings, in `httpd.conf` or in `ssl.conf`? As now I have them divided between the two.

Comment: I suggest you to keep a single vhost file and all the config in same. In Ubuntu, you can do that easily. BTW what is the OS that you use?

Comment: Rather than adding vhost config in httpd.conf, you can add separate vhosts in CentOS. Please refer **Step four (Create New Virtual Host Files)** in [How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7)